# How to avoid scaling dummy variables in dataframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, scale, data-cleaning, standardized

I want to standardise all my variables before applying machine learning methods. However, to my understanding, dummy variables should never be standardised.
After entering the following code, r standardized all my variables, even the ones which are binary. How can I avoid this happening?

```
#standardize all non-categorical variables to have mean zero and a standard deviation of one

df_standardized <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale))
```

I checked my data types are they are "int", not numeric.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: An `int` type is an integer and is considered a numeric type. Did you just want to scale the numeric, non-integer values? Try `is.double` rather than `is.numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale` returns a matrix, we can convert the matrix to vector by either `as.numeric` or `as.vector`.  In addition, use `inherits` for only modifying the `numeric` columns

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(where(~ inherits(.x, "numeric")),
         ~ as.numeric(scale(.x))))
```

#### data

```
data(iris)
df <- iris
df$intCol <- 1L
```